# Ayudar a sumar y restar

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ayuda {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num1, num2, resuNi, resuMaq;
        char desea;
        int opcion;

        do{
            System.out.println(" TE PUEDO AYUDAR A " +
                                " 1. SUMAR " +
                                " 2. RESTAR " +
                                " 3. FIN " +
                                " ESCOGER OPCION " );
            opcion = teclado.nextInt();
            switch (opcion){
            case 1: 
                ayudaSumar();
                break;
            case 2:
                ayudaRestar();
                break;
            default;
            }
        while (opcion != 3);    
    }
    public static int ayudaSumar(int num1, int num2, int resuNi, int resuMaq){
        do{
            System.out.print("Ingrese numero 1: ");
            num1 = teclado.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Ingrese numero 2: ");
            num2 = teclado.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Ingrese resultado: ");
            resuNi = teclado.nextInt();

            resuMaq = num1 + num2;

            if ( resuMaq == resuNi ){
                system.out.print("La suma esta correcta");
            } else {
                system.out.print("La suma esta incorrecta");
            }
            System.out.print("¿Desea revisar otra suma (S/N)");
            desea = teclado.nextchar();
            while ( desea == S );
        }
    }   
    public static int ayudaRestar(int num1, int num2, int resuNi, int resuMaq){
        do{
            System.out.print("Ingrese numero 1: ");
            num1 = teclado.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Ingrese numero 2: ");
            num2 = teclado.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Ingrese resultado: ");
            resuNi = teclado.nextInt();

            resuMaq = num1 - num2;

            if ( resuMaq == resuNi ){
                system.out.print("La resta esta correcta");
            } else {
                system.out.print("La resta esta incorrecta");
            }
            System.out.print("¿Desea revisar otra resta (S/N)");
            desea = teclado.nextchar();
            while ( desea == S );
        }
    }
}
```

Si me pueden indicar por favor donde estan las fallas. Necesito ofrecer un menú para escoger lo que se desea hacer(suma o resta), en caso de que se escoja la opción 1 o sea suma, enseguida se debe introducir los dos numeros que se van a sumar y su resultado, luego la computadora verifica si es correcto o incorrecto y despues pregunta si desea revisar otra suma. Si es así debe repetir todo el proceso. Por lo cual se hace un metodo para la suma y otro para la resta.

Comment: Y cuál es el problema con tu código?

Comment: me sale error en la linea 19, 22, 24 y tambien con la palabra teclado

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Métodos que no regresan valor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/275190/m%c3%a9todos-que-no-regresan-valor)

Answer (score 1):

Compañero he realizado unas modificaciones en tu código respetando la idea que tienes, claramente parte del problema esta cuando invocas los métodos, ya que no pasas ningún parámetro a tratar. De igual forma no inicializas ninguno de los parámetros y no implementas correctamente el `do-while` y el `swicth`.

*Los temas estéticos tu claramente puedes corregirlos.

```
public class Ayuda {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int resuNi = 0;
    int resuMaq = 0;
    String desea = "";
    int opcion;

    do {
        System.out.println(" TE PUEDO AYUDAR A " +
                            " 1. SUMAR " +
                            " 2. RESTAR " +
                            " 3. FIN " +
                            " ESCOGER OPCION " );
        opcion = teclado.nextInt();
        switch (opcion) {
        case 1:
            ayudaSumar(teclado, num1, num2, resuNi, resuMaq, desea);
            break;
        case 2:
            ayudaRestar(teclado, num1, num2, resuNi, resuMaq, desea);
            break;
        default:
        }
    } while (opcion != 3);

}

public static int ayudaSumar(Scanner teclado, int num1, int num2, int resuNi, int resuMaq, String desea){
        do{
            System.out.print("Ingrese numero 1: ");
            num1 = teclado.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Ingrese numero 2: ");
            num2 = teclado.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Ingrese resultado: ");
            resuNi = teclado.nextInt();

            resuMaq = num1 + num2;

            if ( resuMaq == resuNi ){
                System.out.print("La suma esta correcta");
            } else {
                System.out.print("La suma esta incorrecta");
            }
            System.out.print("¿Desea revisar otra suma (S/N)");
            desea = teclado.next();
        } while (desea.equalsIgnoreCase("S") );
        return resuMaq;

    }

public static int ayudaRestar(Scanner teclado, int num1, int num2, int resuNi, int resuMaq, String desea) {
    do {
        System.out.print("Ingrese numero 1: ");
        num1 = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Ingrese numero 2: ");
        num2 = teclado.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Ingrese resultado: ");
        resuNi = teclado.nextInt();

        resuMaq = num1 - num2;

        if (resuMaq == resuNi) {
            System.out.print("La resta esta correcta");
        } else {
            System.out.print("La resta esta incorrecta");
        }
        System.out.print("¿Desea revisar otra resta (S/N)");
        desea = teclado.next();
    } while (desea.equalsIgnoreCase("S"));
    return resuMaq;

 }

}
```

Pruebalo, creo que te servirá.