# Métodos que no regresan valor

Tags: java, jvm

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ayuda {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num1; 
        int num2; 
        int resuNi; 
        int resuMaq;
        char desea = 'S';
        int opcion;

        do{
            System.out.println(" TE PUEDO AYUDAR A " +
                                " 1. SUMAR " +
                                " 2. RESTAR " +
                                " 3. FIN " +
                                " ESCOGER OPCION " );
            opcion = teclado.nextInt();
            switch (opcion){
            case 1: 
                ayudaSumar(teclado, num1, num2, resuNi, resuMaq, desea);
                break;
            case 2:
                ayudaRestar(teclado, num1, num2, resuNi, resuMaq, desea);
                break;
            default:
            }
        } while (opcion != 3);  
    }
    public static void ayudaSumar(int num1, int num2, int resuNi, int resuMaq, char desea ){
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        do{
            System.out.print("Ingrese numero 1: ");
            num1 = teclado.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Ingrese numero 2: ");
            num2 = teclado.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Ingrese rsultado: ");
            resuNi = teclado.nextInt();

            resuMaq = num1 + num2;

            if ( resuMaq == resuNi ){
                System.out.print("La suma esta correcta");
            } else {
                System.out.print("La suma esta incorrecta");
            }
            System.out.print("¿Desea revisar otra suma (S/N)");
            desea = teclado.nextChar();
            } while ( desea == 'S' );
        }

    public static void ayudaRestar(int num1, int num2, int resuNi, int resuMaq, char desea){
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        do{
            System.out.print("Ingrese numero 1: ");
            num1 = teclado.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Ingrese numero 2: ");
            num2 = teclado.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Ingrese rsultado: ");
            resuNi = teclado.nextInt();

            resuMaq = num1 - num2;

            if ( resuMaq == resuNi ){
                System.out.print("La resta esta correcta");
            } else {
                System.out.print("La resta esta incorrecta");
            }
            System.out.print("¿Desea revisar otra resta (S/N)");
            desea = teclado.nextChar();
            } while ( desea == 'S' );
        }
    }
```

Buenas tardes compañeros si me pueden ayudar por favor, en la fila 23(ayudaSumar) y 26(ayuda restar) me sale error, al igual que en la 50 y 72(nextChar). Lo que quiero es crear un programa que me sirva para revisar el resultado de una suma o resta segun la opcion que escoja, el usuario ingresa los dos numeros y su respuesta y el programa se encarga de verificar si es correcta o incorrecta.

Comment: Saludos recuerda que hay una diferencia entre Java y JavaScript..!!

Comment: Escribir la misma pregunta cada día no ayuda a que te den respuesta más rápido y sí hace más difícil para otros encontrar respuestas a sus propias preguntas.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Ayudar a sumar y restar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/274896/ayudar-a-sumar-y-restar)

Comment: El problema que estás teniendo te lo explica perfectamente @crrlos en su respuesta. No te desanimes nunca a seguir aprendiendo, sobre todo de tus propios errores, y a superarte cada día que en esto radica el éxito. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

El código tiene dos errores: las funciones ayudaSumar  y ayudaRestar esperan 5 parámetros y se les está pasando 6. Y el método `nextChar()` no existe, en su lugar se usa `next().charAt(0)`

Answer (score 1):

Tu programa necesita algunas correcciones rápidas para funcionar:

Basicamente es aplicar el principio responsabilidad única de SOLID al método main, este principio consiste en dejar que un método tenga un único trabajo, en el caso del main es el control del flujo, asíque hay variables que no necesitas tener allí, de esa manera si tienes problemas con la suma o la resta puedes ir al método en aprticular y si tienes problemas con la opción ya sabes qne parte del código buscar. ESto te hará mucho más fácil al depuración y la modificación de tu aplicación, además de que sin notarlo estarás optimizando la ejecucuión, pues las variables no usadas al salir de un método serán marcadas para una recolección de basura que te liberará esos espacios de memoria automáticamente.

para obtener un caracter puedes aplicar el truco que sugiere ccarlos pero no es lo ideal, te explico una vez veas la corrección rápida del código.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ayuda {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int opcion;

        do {
            System.out.println(" TE PUEDO AYUDAR A "
                    + " 1. SUMAR "
                    + " 2. RESTAR "
                    + " 3. FIN "
                    + " ESCOGER OPCION ");
            opcion = teclado.nextInt();
            switch (opcion) {
                case 1: {
                    ayudaSumar(teclado);
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    ayudaRestar(teclado);
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } while (opcion != 3);
    }

    public static void ayudaSumar(Scanner teclado) {
        char desea = 'S';
        int resuMaq;
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int resuNi;
        do {
            System.out.print("Ingrese numero 1: ");
            num1 = teclado.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Ingrese numero 2: ");
            num2 = teclado.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Ingrese rsultado: ");
            resuNi = teclado.nextInt();

            resuMaq = num1 + num2;

            if (resuMaq == resuNi) {
                System.out.print("La suma esta correcta");
            } else {
                System.out.print("La suma esta incorrecta");
            }
            System.out.print("¿Desea revisar otra suma (S/N)");
            desea = teclado.next().charAt(0);
        } while (desea == 'S');
    }

    public static void ayudaRestar(Scanner teclado) {
        char desea = 'S';
        int resuMaq;
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int resuNi;
        do {
            System.out.print("Ingrese numero 1: ");
            num1 = teclado.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Ingrese numero 2: ");
            num2 = teclado.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Ingrese rsultado: ");
            resuNi = teclado.nextInt();

            resuMaq = num1 - num2;

            if (resuMaq == resuNi) {
                System.out.print("La resta esta correcta");
            } else {
                System.out.print("La resta esta incorrecta");
            }
            System.out.print("¿Desea revisar otra resta (S/N)");
            desea = teclado.next().charAt(0);
        } while (desea == 'S');
    }
}
```

Ahora la explicación del caracter..... primero con un chiste en inglés:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como verás lo ideal es hacer tu código a prueba de usuarios, pueden agregar espacios.

por ello un primer intento de corregir eso podría ser

```
desea = teclado.nextLine().trim().charAt(0);
```

pero eso nos lleva a otro posible error..

por ejemplo para la corrida:

```
 TE PUEDO AYUDAR A  1. SUMAR  2. RESTAR  3. FIN  ESCOGER OPCION 
1
Ingrese numero 1: 2
Ingrese numero 2: 2
Ingrese rsultado: 




3
```

esto produciría un

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

porque el caracter sería un `\r\n` o un `\n`

Así que primeor validamos el tamaño y probamos de nuevo:

String linea = teclado.nextLine().trim();
desea = linea.length() > 0 ? linea.charAt(0) : 'N';

Ahora otro escenario que no hemos pensaod es que el usuario pueda apretar más de una tecla... por ejemplo poner `bn`,`as`, o incluso algo loco como `sn` en tu caso, por ejemplo en la corrida:

```
TE PUEDO AYUDAR A  1. SUMAR  2. RESTAR  3. FIN  ESCOGER OPCION 
1
Ingrese numero 1: 2
Ingrese numero 2: 2
Ingrese rsultado: 3
La suma esta incorrecta¿Desea revisar otra suma (S/N) TE PUEDO AYUDAR A  1. SUMAR  2. RESTAR  3. FIN  ESCOGER OPCION 
bn
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

así que mejor olvídate de comparar con un caractér, comparemos cadenas.

Tienes serios problemas de abstracción y se nota que nunca has tenido que hacerle mantenimiento a tu propio código, es más, pareciera como si no estuvieras familiarizado con el paradigma de orientación a objetos, diseño de clases, paradigma funcional o incluso como si no tuvieras práctica con la programación imperativa. Necesitas mucha práctica para el mundo real, pues parece que incluso desarrollar aplicaciones en el modo main te está costando.

Y tal vez no debería, pero con la ingenua esperanza de que al comunidad aprenda algo voy a comaprtir una solución derivada de la tuya que como observarás, prácticamente no se parece a la tuya.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ayuda {

    enum Operacion {
        SUMA("¿Desea revisar otra suma (S/N)",
                "La suma esta correcta", "La suma esta incorrecta"),
        RESTA("¿Desea revisar otra resta (S/N)", "La resta esta correcta",
                "La resta esta incorrecta");

        private String textoParaOtra;
        private String textoOperacionCorrcta;
        private String textoOperacionIncorrecta;

        Operacion(String textoParaOtra, String textoOperacionCorrcta, String textoOperacionIncorrecta) {
            this.textoParaOtra = textoParaOtra;
            this.textoOperacionCorrcta = textoOperacionCorrcta;
            this.textoOperacionIncorrecta = textoOperacionIncorrecta;
        }
    }

    private static final String YES_OPTION = "S";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        int opcion = 4;
        do {
            System.out.println(" TE PUEDO AYUDAR A "
                    + " 1. SUMAR "
                    + " 2. RESTAR "
                    + " 3. FIN "
                    + " ESCOGER OPCION ");

            opcion = leerNumero(teclado);

            switch (opcion) {
                case 1: {
                    verificarOperaciones(teclado, Operacion.SUMA);
                    break;
                }
                case 2: {
                    verificarOperaciones(teclado, Operacion.RESTA);
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } while (opcion != 3);
    }

    private static void verificarOperaciones(Scanner teclado, Operacion operacion) {
        String desea = YES_OPTION;
        do {
            verificaOperacion(teclado, operacion);
            System.out.print(operacion.textoParaOtra);
            desea = teclado.next().trim();
        } while (desea.equalsIgnoreCase(YES_OPTION));
    }

    private static void verificaOperacion(Scanner teclado, Operacion operacion) {
        System.out.print("Ingrese numero 1: ");
        int num1 = leerNumero(teclado);
        System.out.print("Ingrese numero 2: ");
        int num2 = leerNumero(teclado);
        System.out.print("Ingrese rsultado: ");
        int resuNi = leerNumero(teclado);

        int resuMaq = operacion == Operacion.SUMA ? num1 + num2 : num1 - num2;

        if (resuMaq == resuNi) {
            System.out.println(
                    operacion == Operacion.SUMA
                            ? Operacion.SUMA.textoOperacionCorrcta
                            : Operacion.RESTA.textoOperacionCorrcta
            );
        } else {
            System.out.println(
                    operacion == Operacion.RESTA
                            ? Operacion.SUMA.textoOperacionIncorrecta
                            : Operacion.RESTA.textoOperacionIncorrecta
            );
        }

    }

    private static int leerNumero(Scanner teclado) {
        try {
            return teclado.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
            System.err.println("Por favor ingresa un número");
            teclado.next();
            return leerNumero(teclado);
        }
    }
}
```

Como verás, aún necesita trabajo para hacer que agregar una nueva operación sea una tarea sencilla, pero el tiempo necesario para realizar modificaciones de mantenimiento ha sido drásticamente reducido.

Comment: Pienso que en vez aclarar la duda o resolver el problema específico que tiene (que por otra parte no tiene nada que ver con aplicar SOLID, refactorizaciones, abstracciones, etc, etc, etc, sino con pasar un número erroneo de parámetros a los métodos llamados) te has dedicado a resaltar todas aquellas carencias que tiene su código/solución desde un punto profesional, sin pensar en que quizás esta persona esté comenzando ahora en su carrera como desarrollador. Este tipo de actitudes lejos de ayudar desaniman y hacen sentir a las personas inferiores. Imagino que al igual que todos comenzaste...

Comment: ...tu carrera sin tener el amplio caudal de conocimientos que tienes ahora.

Comment: @E.Betanzos como verás inicio la respuesta poniendo las correcciones que debe hacer para que su código funcione que es su duda específica (pues de hecho él no sabía que algo estaba mal y en la pregunta anterior no usó la solución que le dieron). No es un usuario que contribuya a la comunidad y solamente nos hace malgastar nuestro tiempo preguntando lo mismo una y otra vez. Respondí no por él, sino por la comunidad. Lamento que pienses que la respuesta no es útil a nadie y por ello hayas votado negativamente. Yo llevo cerca de 20 años programando, así que creeme no pasé por lo que los demás.